# MVC: How to use (render) sections from parent (master) View (Layout View)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given views hierarchy: Index.cshtml -> _Layout.cshtml -> _MasterLayout.cshtml :

**_MasterLayout.cshtml** - the set of sections which I want to use in master layout (below)

```
@section javascriptLinks {
<script src="~/client/vendor/require-jquery.js" data-main="~/client/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
@RenderBody()
```

**_Layout.cshtml** - actual site master layout

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- actual site layout here -->
<body>
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("javascriptLinks")
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.cshtml** - some concrete page specific markup

The idea of splitting _Layout.cshtml and  _MasterLayout.cshtml is code sharing. I have a kind of library/framework and _MasterLayout belongs to this library. And _Layout.cshtml is a concrete application site master layout.

Unfortunately, this schema doesn't work. During rendering _Layout.cshtml won't see sections from _MasterLayout.cshtml.

Is there any way to use sections in such a case (taking them from a parent View not from a child View)?

One possible solution I can see is creating separate pages for each section in my _MasterLayout.cshtml and call @RenderPage in _Layout. But, I'd like to have a single sharing asset (_MasterLayout.cshtml).

Answer (score 5):

Try to reverse the operation.
I mean like this:

your **_MasterLayout.cshtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    @RenderSection("HeadSection", true)
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()

// ...... 
// You could put your general scripts here
<script src="~/client/vendor/require-jquery.js" data-main="~/client/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
// Put true to enforce the sub layout to define Scripts section
    @RenderSection("Scripts", true)
</body>
</html>
```

Your **_Layout.cshtml:**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/_Shared/_LayoutMain.cshtml"; }
@section HeadSection{
    // any thing you want
    @RenderSection("HeadSection", false)
}
    @RenderBody()
// ...... 
// Put false to make Scripts section optional
@section Scripts{
    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
}
```

Comment: This makes sense indeed but _Layout.cshtml becomes unnatural (instead of html markup it have to contain the set of @section declarations). I'd like _Layout.cshtml to contain the whole page layout and only import "standard" parts (i.e. sections) from some (easily shared) source.